# Optimizing Merge in Delta Lake (Databricks Open Source )

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization, databricks

I am trying to implement merge using delta lake oss and my history data is around 7 billions records and delta is around 5 millions.

The merge is based on the composite key(5 columns).

I am spinning up a 10 node cluster r5d.12xlarge(~3TB MEMORY / ~480 CORES).

The job took 35 Minutes for first time and the subsequent runs are taking more time.

Tried using optimization techniques , but nothing worked and i started to get heap memory issues after 3 runs , i see lot spill on disk while data shuffles, tried with re writing the history using order by on merge keys ,got performance improvement and  merge completed in 20 minutes and the spill was around 2TB ,however the problem is that  the data written as part of merge process was not in same order as I have no control on order of writing data ,so subsequent runs are taking longer  .

I was not able to use Zorder in delta lake oss as it only comes with subscription .I tried compaction but that did not help either .
Please let me know if there is a better way to optimize the merge process .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recommendation, it seems you are running your databricks notebook on AWS.

The way to optimize it to use Hive metastore or any catalog service alongside. Now how this will help?

While saving the data you can use `bucketing` to order you data according to the merge keys and this metadata information needs to be stored in the metastore which will require hive.

If you use bucketing the data will be in order and will not result in excessive shuffling of data which will inevitably improve the performance of your job.

I am not very sure about databricks but if you use EMR you gets the options to use glue catalog as metastore or you can have your own metastore in EMR also.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your recommendation. I am trying to read and write data from s3.
Looks like while using EMR and delta lake, there is lot of data shuffle and spill in memory and on disk. Not sure, how i can reduce the shuffle and spill since i don't have any control on delta table partitions.

Comment: Keep the data in s3 itself but keep its metadata information and use cluster by to save the data which will enable your data with less shuffle

Comment: Is bucketing possible with the delta lake format?

Answer (score 0):

20 min sounds pretty good in my experience;) What is your partition scheme? Merges are slowed in the same way that SELECTS are, so if you can eliminate lake scans by way of partition filters, that should help tremendously.

Also take a look at the shuffle partitions settings in spark, as I have found these to have a huge impact on performance.

Lastly, compacting you data will have a huge impact on merge performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues, same data size as well. I'm going to get rid of the merge statement and break it into two pieces.

1. Join where match, so UPSATE statement.
2. Join where no match, INSERT.

Comment: did it solve your issue?

Answer (score -2):

If you really want optimize it through code , you can Launching parallel tasks. this is sample code which we have used to parallelized for S3 writing . You can use same logic for adls location as well .

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=total_days+1) as e:
  print(f"{raw_bucket}/{db}/{table}/")
  for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    curr_date = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    jobs.append(e.submit(writeS3, curr_date))

  for job in futures.as_completed(jobs):
    result_done = job.result()
    print(f"Job Completed - {result_done}")

print("Task complete")
```

ref : https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: how it's related to the question about Delta MERGE?